# Can I configure four JMeter clients and gather data as one document?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to install the JMeter client on each desktop, and then gather data from where each JMeter client generate after it run test. Using these data, I want to make chart for TPS over threads and bytes throughput over threads.

Answer (score 1):

You can use step by step guide provided by jmeter [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf).